# Finding Conditional Probabilities, and Independence from Joint Probability Distribution Table

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, independence, bayes-theorem

I have the following joint probability distribution table,

|  | E | E | ~E | ~E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | G | ~G | G | ~G |
| F | a | b | c | d |
| ~F | w | x | y | z |

a+b+c+d+w+x+y+z = 1

Given that F is True, I need to find,

1. P(E|F,G)
2. P(E|F,~G)
3. P(G|F,E)
4. P(G|F,~E)

To find these, is it just as simple as going into the table, and finding that value where E is true, for F is True and G is True (for the first one, and so on) which is "a", or is there a more complex calculation needed?

Other than this, I also need to find whether E and G are conditionally independent, given F. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> To find these, is it just as simple as going into the table, and finding that value where E is true, for F is True and G is True (for the first one, and so on) which is "a", or is there a more complex calculation needed?

It is just a bit more complex.  That is the method to find the joint probability, $\mathsf P(E,F,G)=a$, but that is not entirely what you want.

You'll need to use the definition of conditional probability, and the Law of Total Probability:

$\qquad\mathsf P(F\mid E, G) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(E,F,G)}{\mathsf P(E,F,G)+\mathsf P(E,{\neg}F,G)}=\dfrac{a}{a+w}$

[Note: this is *not* one of yours, but they are solved similarly.]

> Other than this, I also need to find whether E and G are conditionally independent, given F. How do I do this?

Find those conditional probabilities and you will have it.  $E$ and $G$ are conditionally independent under $F$ exactly when $\mathsf P(E\mid F,G)=\mathsf P(E\mid F, \neg G)$, and this will also be when $\mathsf P(G\mid E,F)=\mathsf P(G\mid \neg E, F)$.

Comment: Makes sense, Now, if I want to find the values of P(E | G), P(E | ~G), P(G | E) and P(G | ~E), how would I go about doing that using the above table?

Comment: Same process.$$\mathsf P(E\mid G)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(E,F,G)+\mathsf P(E,\neg F,G)}{\mathsf P(E,F,G)+\mathsf P(E,\neg F,G)+\mathsf P(\neg E,F,G)+\mathsf P(\neg E,\neg F,G)}$$